# jquery get all elements matching data attribute name

Tags: jquery

say i have a few elements with the following data attribute:

```
<data-my-key="blah">
```

and i want to attach an event to them all, how can this be done?

I have tried a few things but cant get it to work.

My latest attempt was:

```
$('data-my-key').click(...
```

and

```
$(document).find('data-my-key').click(...
```

Comment: A note on how you're using the selector. Just using the name would select the element. Meaning, the way you had it with just a string, $('div').click would select all DIV elements. $('#div') would select elements with id='div' and $('.div') would select elements with a class='div'. Of course, it would be strange to give an element an ID or Class of div but it's just an example on selection syntax.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
$('[data-my-key]').click(...
```

Note however, that jQuery stores `data` attributes added after DOM load in it's internal cache not as an attribute on the element, so that selector would not work for those. In that case you would need to use `filter`:

```
$(document).children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('my-key');
}).click(...;
```

Comment: damn!! - i was so close :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and give the attribute name.

```
$('[data-my-key]').click...
```